# Android Alert Dialog view to Parent View

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a Alert Dialog builder where it shows EditText Box and few others.Now i need to 
convert that into Normal View(Parent View) .

Adding the code:

public synchronized void showPopUp(final String picturePath) {

```
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LinearLayout alertLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    InputFilter[] inputFilter = new InputFilter[1];
    inputFilter[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(50);

    alertLayout.setOrientation(1); // 1 is for vertical orientation
    final EditText nameInput = new EditText(this);
    nameInput.setHint("Receipt Name");
    nameInput.setFilters(inputFilter);
    ;
    nameInput.setSingleLine(true);

    final TextView dateText = new TextView(this);
    dateText.setText("Receipt Date");

    final EditText amtInput = new EditText(this);
    amtInput.setHint("Receipt Amount");
    amtInput.setSingleLine(true);

    DigitsKeyListener digitKeyListener = new DigitsKeyListener(false, true);
    amtInput.setKeyListener(digitKeyListener);

    InputFilter[] amtInputFilter = new InputFilter[2];
    amtInputFilter[0] = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (end > start) {
                String destTxt = dest.toString();
                String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart)
                        + source.subSequence(start, end)
                        + destTxt.substring(dend);
                if (!resultingTxt
                        .matches("^\\$?\\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\\,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\\d{0,}(\\.\\d{0,2})?|0(\\.\\d{0,2})?|(\\.\\d{1,2}))$|^\\-?\\$?([1-9]{1}\\d{0,2}(\\,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\\d{0,}(\\.\\d{0,2})?|0(\\.\\d{0,2})?|(\\.\\d{1,2}))$|^\\(\\$?([1-9]{1}\\d{0,2}(\\,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\\d{0,}(\\.\\d{0,2})?|0(\\.\\d{0,2})?|(\\.\\d{1,2}))\\)$")) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    amtInputFilter[1] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(13);
    amtInput.setFilters(amtInputFilter);

    amtInput.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (event != null && event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                return false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
                || event == null
                || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {                  


                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(amtInput.getWindowToken(), 0);


            }
            return false;
        }



});

final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(this);

    datePicker.clearFocus();
    datePicker.bringToFront();



    alertLayout.addView(nameInput);
    alertLayout.addView(amtInput);
    alertLayout.addView(dateText);
    alertLayout.addView(datePicker);
    scrollView.addView(alertLayout);
    alert.setView(scrollView);

    alert.setTitle("Enter Expense Detail");

    alert.setPositiveButton("SAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            rcptName = nameInput.getText().toString();
            rcptAmt = amtInput.getText().toString();

            int spinnerDate = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            int spinnerMonth = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;

            if (spinnerMonth < 10 && spinnerDate < 10) {
                rcptDate = (datePicker.getYear()) + "0" + (spinnerMonth)
                        + "0" + spinnerDate;
            } else if (spinnerMonth < 10) {
                rcptDate = (datePicker.getYear()) + "0" + (spinnerMonth)
                        + "" + spinnerDate;
            } else if (spinnerDate < 10) {
                rcptDate = (datePicker.getYear()) + "" + (spinnerMonth)
                        + "0" + spinnerDate;
            } else {
                rcptDate = (datePicker.getYear()) + "" + (spinnerMonth)
                        + "" + spinnerDate;
            }

            SavePreferences("RNAME", rcptName);
            SavePreferences("RAMOUNT", rcptAmt);
            SavePreferences("RDATE", rcptDate);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                    "LoginPref", 0);
            String username = sharedPreferences.getString("USERNAME", null);
            String guid = sharedPreferences.getString("GUID", null);
            String password = sharedPreferences.getString("PASSWORD", null);
            String rcptName = sharedPreferences.getString("RNAME", null);
            String rcptAmount = sharedPreferences
                    .getString("RAMOUNT", null);
            String rcptDate = sharedPreferences.getString("RDATE", null);
            String uploadLocation = sharedPreferences.getString("LOGINURL",
                    null);


            if (rcptAmount.isEmpty() || rcptName == null
                    || rcptName.isEmpty() || rcptName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                showPopUp(picturePath);

            } else {


                if (isInternetOn()) {

                    new UploadTask().execute(picturePath, username, guid,
                            rcptName, rcptAmount, rcptDate, uploadLocation,
                            password);

                } else {


                    finish();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    alert.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // whitelist allowed keys - allow navigation keys only
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            });

    alert.setCancelable(false);

    alert.show();

}
```

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: can you provide your code snippet??

Comment: Please provide your code.